# How to spyOn an internal static function call?

Tags: node.js, vitest

I have the following event handler and I want to test that updateOrAddNew is being called.

```js
const { Events } = require('client');
const User = require('../models/User');

module.exports = {
    name: Events.MemberAdd,
    async execute(member) {
        User.updateOrAddNew(member);
    }
}
```

I've written the following test:

```js
import {it, expect, vi } from 'vitest';
import User from '../models/User';
import memberAdd from './memberAdd';


it('calls updateOrAddNew on memberAdd', async () => {
    const spy = vi.spyOn(User, 'updateOrAddNew').mockReturnValue(true);
    User.updateOrAddNew = spy;
    const member = {...};

    await memberAdd.execute(member);

    expect(spy).toBeCalled();
});
```

I've tried numerous different syntax but the `spy` is never called. `updateOrAddNew` is a static method. How can I test whether it's being called when `memberAdd.execute` is run?

I'm pretty new to testing so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you please share part of `User`? Is it a class?

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the fact that `memberAdd` is a CommonJS module and Vitest cannot replace or augment the `User` class it is importing with the mock function. If you mock the entire User class and add some logs, you can see that the User class in the test is different than the one in the `memberAdd` function. Additionally, converting it to an ES module seems to make the test work without any other modifications. There might be workarounds if that is not an option, but Vitest (and Vite) are generally ESM-first.

Comment: @M.Desjardins Yeah, I inspected it and saw that it wasn't the spy that was being called. I assumed it was something like that.

Answer (score 0):

What if you declare in that file globally like this:

```
jest.spyOn(User, 'updateOrAddNew').mockReturnValue(true);
```

This should update any usage of this method with mock

Comment: That still doesn't seem to mock properly.

Comment: Meaning this User.updateOrAddNew does not return true in any of the tests you run?

Comment: Not the OP, but that is correct in my demo setup. Note that this question is using Vitest, not Jest. With Vitest, declaring the mock at the top-level, it is not using the mocked function in the `memberAdd.js` module. Calling the function manually in the test uses the mocked function (as expected), it just doesn't use the mocked version in a CommonJS module (like `memberAdd.js`). Therefore, calling `memberAdd.execute(member)` uses the original `User.updateOrAddNew` function, not the mocked version.